# Nginx & node.js unknown directive

Tags: node.js, nginx, configuration, http-proxy

I'm trying to write a config file for nginx and I'm getting this error:

> unknown directive "proxy_http_version" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.conf:24

**Config file location:** /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.conf

**Nginx Version:** I have nginx/1.0.15 installed.

And this is my configuration file. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
upstream node_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # !!! handle static content requests and serve with nginx !!! #
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
        root        /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public/;
    }

    # !!! handle dynamic content requests and serve with node defined in upstream node_app object. !!! #
    location ~* ^[^\.]+$ {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://node_app;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

update nginx ! the proxy_http_version feature was added in NGINX version 1.1.4

Comment: I have 1.12.0 and it is mid 2017. Still getting the exact same error...

Comment: I use 1.21.3-alpine image from nginx docker hub registry and got the same